# USB mouse is dead on power on

Tags: usb, mouse, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10 workstation, freshly installed, most recent updates.

Since about a week, the mouse is dead when powering up. Usually it will be recognised after some 10+ secs and works then normally, except that in fine mark/drag&drop operations over test lines, marking does not work reliable (seems as if the mark status is briefly set off and set on randomly, resulting in changing marked areas).

`lsusb` shows the following (directly after power up, and +20 secs):

```
user@user-B360M-D3H:~$ lsusb  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046a:0180 Cherry GmbH   
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 18a5:0237 Verbatim, Ltd Portable Harddrive  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
user@user-D3H:~$ lsusb  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046a:0180 Cherry GmbH   
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:0811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 18a5:0237 Verbatim, Ltd Portable Harddrive  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub   
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:081b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C310  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]  
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
user@user-B360M-D3H:~$   

OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64   
Host: B360M-D3H   
Kernel: 5.3.0-29-generic   
Uptime: 16 mins   
Packages: 2459 (dpkg), 6 (snap)   
Shell: bash 5.0.3   
Resolution: 1680x1050   
DE: GNOME 3.34.1   
WM: GNOME Shell   
WM Theme: Adwaita   
Theme: Yaru-light [GTK2/3]   
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]   
Terminal: gnome-terminal   
 CPU: Intel i3-8300 (4) @ 3.700GHz   
GPU: Intel 8th Gen Core Processor Ga   
Memory: 1743MiB / 31978MiB
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested that the mouse itself works correctly? You can try in another computer or in the same computer when running a live system (in an Ubuntu USB boot drive).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with a live linux dvd, I tried, and the same problem.

Comment: Then we can suspect a hardware problem: probably the mouse itself (or maybe the USB port or USB system in the computer).

Comment: I tried the mouse at another pc and it worked normal.

Answer (score 1):

I did a systematic check of the usb devices connected to the USB slots, and which bus and port belong to each slot using

lsusb -t

and

dmesg

I checked the status with lsusb -t first, unplugged one device if used, checked again and identified the bus and port number; then I plugged a USB memory stick to the tested slot to check its functionality. I did this step by step for all usb slots, so I could identify the Bus/port address of each usb slot.

I found out that the mouse has been on a USB 3.1 bus beneith a Reiner SCT smart card reader on the next port in my configuration when the problem occured reproducible. I replugged the mouse to the USB 2.0 ports beneith the PS/2 plug, and the keyboard on the second one up there, and attached all usb devices with higher transfer loads to USB 3.1 slots.

This solved the problem (at least until now). Probably, these two ports (bus 1 port 5 and port 6, both throwing -110 and -62 errors during boot) are prioritized for usb keyboard and mouse. Since they had been unused, timeouts and/or USB3.1 protocol issues may have occured until the mouse finally (after up to 25 secs) had been found at the USB 3.1 port and became active.

Strangely, this problem did not occur under the previous versions on the same hardware and USB configuration (16.04 to 19.04), and only since about a week ago (Ubunutu or VirtualBox with Win10 guest update?)

Hope this workaround keeps working.

Comment: +1; Thanks for sharing your analysis and solution (or should we say workaround) :-)